# Android flutter's flutter_webview_plugin plugin's webview shows loading indicator and nothing else

Tags: android, webview, dart, flutter

I have been building a flutter android app with flutter_webview_plugin. My problem is when I use back button of android phone the web view rather than closing shows the loading indicator and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem we will have to listen both the webview's onDestroy status and navigator's pop-ability and then we will pop the webview route (screen).
To do this we will just write this code within the build method where the WebviewScaffold is returned.

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onDestroy.listen((_){
      if(Navigator.canPop(context)){
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    });
```

> Problem solved   :)

*note flutterWebviewPlugin is an object of FlutterWebviewPlugin declared out of the build method.*